# Linux: disable man from showing mans in non-English languages

Tags: linux, environment-variables, translation, manpages, man

On my Linux there are some outdated translated mans installed. I want to prohibit `man` utility from showing them.

I want to do this permanently, while saving a current locale.

What environment settings should I change (`setenv` in `.profile`) to limit man to one language?

I have no root and can't just delete outdated mans or to strace a man utility.

Comment: in the future, use the `edit` button to add details to your answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `LANG` to `C` or to `en_US`. This will be affect of all programs unless you add an alias for man that sets the variable accordingly.

```
alias man='LANG=C man'
```

[edit: I tested it, `LC_MESSAGES` changed the error message language, but not the manpage language]

Comment: Hi, please look in the Q: `"I want to do this permanently, while saving a current locale."` - LANG is a locale.